# Exceptionally bad at understanding exceptions

Tags: php, exception, pdo

So I am busy moving over to PDO (yes, i'm still oldschool mysql driver like that) and I have never used exceptions before. My code below is based on what I understand thus far. My application where I will be needing this will create 3 seperate database connections, 2 of which will be mysql and 1 mssql (hence the type if else).

The problem is that even if I provide incorrect connection values, it still processes and continues with the script, and skips the "catch"  entirely, as if there was no error. I understand that the basics should be:

```
 try {
      if("condition" != "conditions") {
           throw new Exception("Oops I did it again");
      }
 catch(Exceptions as e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
 }
```

I also understand that PDO will through the exceptions so I dont have to throw, but it's just not working out, please help and also give me a bit more oversight as to what I am misunderstanding about this concept:

```
 // connect(): Connect to a database (MySQL):

private function connect($cred) {
    $type = $cred['type'];
    if($type == "mysql") {
        try {
            $handler = new PDO("mysql:host".$cred['credentials']['server'].";dbname=".$cred['credentials']['database'].", ".$cred['credentials']['username'].",".$cred['credentials']['password']);
            if($cred['errors'] == 'exception') {
                $handler->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            } elseif($cred['errors'] == 'warning') {
                $handler->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
            } else {
                $handler->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT );
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->informer("FATAL","An error has occured trying to connect to the connection (".$cred['name'].") -".$e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return $handler;
    }
}
```

Comment: And you're sure that `$cred['errors']` is set to `'exception'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, it was a syntax issue above in my PDO objection creation, I had:

```
 $handler = new PDO("mysql:host".$cred['credentials']['server'].";dbname=".$cred['credentials']['database'].", ".$cred['credentials']['username'].",".$cred['credentials']['password']);
```

and it should have been:

```
 $handler = new PDO("mysql:host=".$cred['credentials']['server'].";dbname=".$cred['credentials']['database'].", ".$cred['credentials']['username'].",".$cred['credentials']['password']);
```

Comment: And that didn't throw a PDOException??

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, but to receive a PDO exception from the constructor you may have to pass the attributes in the `new` call:

```
new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
```

**Update**

Just tested that, but it throws the exception even without passing the attribute.